# sort json results in foreach loop

Tags: php, json, foreach, usort

I am running a foreach loop to display json results, when certain conditions are met, and would like to sort them by the `name` field. I am trying `usort()`, but can't seem to figure it out.

JSON:

```
{
    "Shawn Taylor":{
        "name":"Shawn Taylor",
        "title":"",
        "photo_url":"house_165 (1).jpg",
        },
    "Another Name": {
        "name":"Another Name",
        "title":"Title is here",
        "photo_url":"Person.jpg",
        }
}
```

PHP:

```
$data_json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data_array = json_decode($data_json, true);
$i = 0;
foreach($data_array as $key => $person){
  if($person['title'] == 'some title'){
    include('card.php'); 
    if(++$i % 4 === 0) {
      echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>'; // inserts a clearfix every 4 cards
    }
  }
}
```

So this returns the all the results I expect, but not sorted. I've tried usort() a few different ways, but just fell on my face terribly:) Please help!

Comment: You can't iterate through JSON in a for loop in PHP. You need to decode it first. `json_decode($data_array, true);`

Comment: I've already decoded - edited my question to include it

Comment: BTW, why the -1 on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use json_decode first to convert to php array, set the flag to TRUE for associative array `$myarr = json_decode($array, TRUE)`
the try custom usort

```
 // Sort the multidimensional array
 usort($myarr, "custom_sort");
 // Define the custom sort function
 function custom_sort($a,$b) {
      return $a['name']>$b['name'];
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! it wasn't working at first because I had this inside another foreach loop a level above what I described here, which I guess isn't allowed (got a Cannot redeclare custom_sort() )... once I put it outside all levels of foreach loops, it was good to go!

Answer (score 2):

Your json is improperly formatted. There's a couple extra commas, one after each JPG item. Removed below.

Then, `json_decode` the json string to a PHP associative array, and, since you're using the names as json indexes, `ksort` (key sort) the resulting array.

```
$json_string = '{
    "Shawn Taylor":{
        "name":"Shawn Taylor",
        "title":"",
        "photo_url":"house_165 (1).jpg"
        },
    "Another Name": {
        "name":"Another Name",
        "title":"Title is here",
        "photo_url":"Person.jpg"
        }
}';

$data_array = json_decode($json_string, true);
ksort($data_array);

// the remaining code
```

A `print_r` after the `ksort` displays:

```
Array
(
    [Another Name] => Array
        (
            [name] => Another Name
            [title] => Title is here
            [photo_url] => Person.jpg
        )

    [Shawn Taylor] => Array
        (
            [name] => Shawn Taylor
            [title] => 
            [photo_url] => house_165 (1).jpg
        )

)
```

If you need to sort by a nested index, and you want to maintain the associative array, use `uasort`:

```
uasort($data_array, 'sort_name_index');

function sort_name_index($a, $b) {
  return $a['name'] > $b['name'];
}
```

Comment: you're right about the extra comma, I just forgot to take it out when I removed a whole bunch of extra fields for this example... as for ksort, it works and is very simple, but I actually want to sort by the "name" field for other reasons. there may be situations where they won't match up.

Comment: Then simply swap my ksort for the usort in Conceptz's answer.